# GWT FocusPanel adds input field in firefox

Tags: firefox, gwt

http://s15.postimage.org/fgdp9gqzf/Focus_Panel.png

Now the button and the label are not aligned. If I remove the FocusPanel is seems to work fine. The only reason I have a FocusPanel is for event handling.

I tried setting the border, padding on the FocusPanel to zero but it did not change anything.

I am using firefox 11.0

Answer (score 2):

The `<input>` element is the only way for GWT to implement focus handling, setting a tab stop, etc. It shouldn't be visible or affect your layout.  You can safely ignore it.

The alignment of your button and label can be specified with CSS.

Comment: Actually, the hidden input is for access-keys; only old webkits need it for focus. See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/impl/FocusImplStandard.java#33